# $N$ people sitting at $k$ seats at round table. Expectation of number of pairs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What I have is a somewhat upgrade version of seating $N$ people on $k$ seats at a round table.

The question is about the expectation of number of people sitting in pairs. Here is the more specific rule: 3 people sitting in a row is only counted as one pair; 4 people sitting in a row counts as two pairs; 5 people sitting in a row counts as two pairs... In short, for any odd number $N_{odd}$ people sitting in a row, it counts as $\frac{N_{odd}-1}{2}$ pairs (since the extra person is not forming any pair). For an even number of people, it is $\frac{N_{odd}}{2}$ pairs.

I started with the simple case of 3 seats, 1 person. Apparently no pair can be formed by a single person so expectation here is 0.

In the simple case of 3 seats, 2 people, the two occupied seats are always next to each other. So the expectation here is 1 pair.

In the case of 4 seats, 2 people. There are 6 arrangements, where 4 of the arrangements contain one pair. So the expectation is $\frac{4\times1}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$.

In the case of 6 seats, 4 people. There are 15 arrangements. Among these 15 arrangements, 10 have 2 pairs and 5 have 1 pair. Expectation is $\frac{10 \times 2 + 5 \times 1}{15}=\frac{25}{15}=\frac{5}{3}$.

How do I generalize this to $N$ people and $k$ seats?